# Multiple conditions in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SELECTION

```
SELECT *
FROM Movies
CROSS JOIN Countries 
WHERE Movies.ID = Countries.ID 
AND Countries.Country = 'South Korea' 
GROUP BY imdbID 
ORDER BY CAST(imdbVotes AS int) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Is it possible to add multiple OR conditions to the third line like so?

```
AND Countries.Country = 'South Korea' OR 'Japan' OR 'China'
```

**bonus question**: Can I set a limit in the statement that limits the query to 100 Japanese movies AND 100 Korean movies but not 100 of both?

Comment: `AND Countries.Country in ('South Korea','Japan','China')`  Why are you using a cross join? every move in every country but then why the movie.id = country.id?  Group by not needed unless you have aggregration.  Better yet.  In english what are you trying to do and provide a sample set of results...

Comment: You probbly don't want `CROSS JOIN` there - it's going to put every country with every movie, which is unlikely.  And the current query is going to get 100 movies, period, regardless of origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```
AND Countries.Country IN ('South Korea', 'Japan', 'China')
```

or muiltiple ORs:

```
AND (Countries.Country = 'South Korea' 
 OR Countries.Country = 'Japan' 
 OR Countries.Country = 'China')
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about the bonus question?

Comment: Do two queries and `UNION` them.

Answer (score -1):

You can query multiple country values like this:

```
AND Countries.Country IN ('South Korea', 'Japan', 'China')
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
AND Countries.Country = 'South Korea'
    OR Countries.Country = 'Japan'
    OR Countries.Country = 'China'
```

Comment: wrap the or in ()'s please do to the other where condition.  Otherwise the'y would get all movies ID matching country ID and country that is south Korea) and those in japan or china.

Comment: xQbert - it's not necessary to wrap these in parenthesis.  It's correct, logically, and syntactically.

Comment: So `WHERE Movies.ID = Countries.ID AND Countries.Country = 'South Korea' OR Countries.Country = 'Japan' OR Countries.Country = 'China'` is the same as `WHERE Movies.ID = Countries.ID AND (Countries.Country = 'South Korea' OR Countries.Country = 'Japan' OR Countries.Country = 'China')`?  SQLLite is an odd one then.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works, that it' unnecessary.  Whenever you mix `AND`/`OR` conditions, wrap them in parenthesis for _clarity_.

Comment: No worries, the banter aids us both.  I may have learned something about sqllite!  I don't have sqlite to test with or I'd run the test myself; but it would have been the 1st engine that behaved that way I would have run into in years.

Comment: @xQbert - agreed.  For some reason, in the original statement, I read that `where countries.country =...` as a join criteria instead of a filter.  I should slow down a little and read more carefully.

Comment: AND has higher precedence than OR.